# Difference between "Зачекати" and "почекати"

Tags: значення-слів, різниця-між-словами, префікс

I was asked about the difference between "Зачекати" and "почекати" or the difference between "Зачекай" and "почекай" but I couldn't explain.

Мене запитали про різницю між значеннями слів "Зачекати" і "почекати" або "Зачекай" і "почекай", однак я не зміг пояснити.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Аргументуємо словниками, наприклад **СУМ-11**.

   - [Зачекати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zachekaty)

     > 1. Чекаючи, діждатися кого-, чого-небудь.
     > 2. Не поспішати робити що-небудь.
   - [Почекати](http://sum.in.ua/s/pochekaty)

     > 1. Чекати якийсь час.
     > 2. Уживається як застереження або нахваляння, погроза.

Якщо порівняти поняття, то здається, що **зачекати** вказує на важливість результату чи якогось моменту, натомість **почекай** на важливість процесу.

2. **Грінченко** представляє оба варіанти без різниці:

   - [Почекати](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/46722-pochekaty.html)
   - [Зачекати](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/18945-zachekaty.html)

     > Подождать

Не дуже інформативно. Можливо проблема у префіксах?

---

Отже, розглянемо [ролі цих префіксів](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0) у дієсловах:

> - Префікси зі значення напряму дії — ви-, в-, об-, **за-**, пере-, до-.
> - Префікси зі значенням початку або кінця дії — **за-**, до-, при-.
> - Префікси зі значенням повторюваності дії — **по-**.
> - Словозмінні префікси для утворення форми [доконаного виду](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4_%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) — з-, **по-**, про-, на-.

Розглянемо по пунктам:

- Нам не підходить, бо наше дієслово не пов'язане з напрямом.
- Важливий початок та кінець процесу.
- Важливість процесу — його повторення.
- Важливий кінець результату чи процесу.

Дещо збігається з описом СУМ-11. Різниця між **зачекай** і **почекай**, що коли вживати перше — маєте на увазі [дочекатися](http://sum.in.ua/s/dochekatysja), а друге — більш ввічливий варіант [постійте тут](http://sum.in.ua/s/stojaty) чи щось кшталт цього.

---

---

1. Let's see dictionaries, for first: **СУМ-11**.

   - [Зачекати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zachekaty)

     > 1. Чекаючи, діждатися кого-, чого-небудь.
     > 2. Не поспішати робити що-небудь.
   - [Почекати](http://sum.in.ua/s/pochekaty)

     > 1. Чекати якийсь час.
     > 2. Уживається як застереження або нахваляння, погроза.

If to compare meanings then **зачекати** is showed on importance of result or moment of something, and **почекай** is showed on importance of moment.

2. **Грінченко** shows both words without difference of meaning.

   - [Почекати](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/46722-pochekaty.html)
   - [Зачекати](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/18945-zachekaty.html)

     > Подождать

It is not informative. Is maybe problem in [prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix)?

---

So, let's see [their roles](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0) in verbs:

> - Префікси зі значення напряму дії — ви-, в-, об-, **за-**, пере-, до-.
> - Префікси зі значенням початку або кінця дії — **за-**, до-, при-.
> - Префікси зі значенням повторюваності дії — **по-**.
> - Словозмінні префікси для утворення форми [доконаного виду](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4_%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) — з-, **по-**, про-, на-.

What we have:

- It isn't our case, because this for "verbs with directions".
- Importance of start or finish of processes.
- Importance of processes — repeating.
- Importance of results or finish of processes.

It is some like the description of СУМ-11. There are difference between **зачекай** and **почекай**, that when to use first verb — it's like [wait me](http://sum.in.ua/s/dochekatysja), and second verb — it's like polite [stay some time here](http://sum.in.ua/s/stojaty) or something this.

---

---

**Не по темі.** Щодо цього чи близько цього, є деякі цікаві обговорення, думки:

- [Полонізми](http://politiko.ua/blogpost42465)
- [І. Р. Вихованець](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine3-10.pdf)

Comment: Так, мені теж здається, що це процес і результат. Як **по**стибай і **за**стрибни. Політай і залети.